# List.Add(object) c#

Tags: c#, list, xna

If I have an object called, `shape`, and I do `myList.Add(shape);`, and later on I do: `shape = GetNewShape();` which resets everything, will the shape within `myList` be affected? Or will it stay the same?

I am having trouble with my XNA application where I have a collection of `shape` objects that and a separate `shape` object which I animate. Once that is done animating, I create a new one to start animating.

Comment: I think you need to read a basic C# tutorial. (the answer is the list won't be affected)

Comment: You need to learn about objects and references.

Comment: When in doubt, fire up and test in console project...

Comment: @Valamas-AUS when in doubt fire up LinqPad (http://www.linqpad.net/) instant coding without the load of Visual Studio. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your shape variable holds just a reference to the shape. If you assign it a new shape object the reference contained in the list will still be the old one.

Calling a method on shape like `shape.DoCrazyStuff();` could alter the object itself and therefore would also be reflected by the object in the list.

But yeah, you should read up on C# basics.

Comment: Your answer seems to assume that that `shape` is a reference type (i.e. a class). If instead its a value type (i.e. a `struct`) then what you say isn't true.